# Querying a local secondary index of dynamoDB using low level java API

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I am trying to query a local secondary index with the hash key.

My table: Table1
Username(hash_key), Id(range_key), timestamp....

My local secondary index(because I want to query all usernames and have it ordered by time)
My LSI: Table1_TimestampLSI
Username(hash_key), timestamp(range_key)

e.g 
user1 | 123 | 12/12/2015 
user1 | 456 | 11/01/2015
user2 | 789 | 12/01/2015

NOTE: I could not just make the timestamp the range key in the table itself because (Username+Timestamp) is not unique. So I had to create a ID field to ensure uniqueness.

Since I want the async client I am using the low level API(model NOT document) java API.

Function to query index

```
HashMap<String, Condition> queryFilter = new HashMap<String, Condition>();
        Condition condition = new Condition()
                .withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.EQ.toString())
                .withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue().withS(username));
        queryFilter.put("Username", condition);

        QueryRequest queryRequest = new QueryRequest(tableName + "_TimestampLSI").withQueryFilter(queryFilter);

        queryRequest.setScanIndexForward(false);

        Future<QueryResult> fQueryResult = dynamoDB.queryAsync(queryRequest,
            new AsyncHandler<QueryRequest,QueryResult>() {
                public void onSuccess(QueryRequest request, QueryResult result) {
                    System.out.println("Table: " + result);
                }

                public void onError(Exception exception) {
                    System.out.println("Error describing table: " + exception.getMessage());
                    // Callers can also test if exception is an instance of 
                    // AmazonServiceException or AmazonClientException and cast 
                    // it to get additional information
                }             
            });

        System.out.println("Result: " + fQueryResult);
```

I get the following error
Error describing table: Either the KeyConditions or KeyConditionExpression parameter must be specified in the request. (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException;

Am I missing something? Thought I should be able to query an index just on the hash value.

Answer (score 0):

You've misunderstood Local Indices.

A [Query](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html) always takes a hash key. So your `QueryRequest` should have has a `setHashKeyValue` setup.

You can't cross-hash a query, not with hash+range primary key and not with LSI. You can do that with GSI but I'm not sure how this will help you here.

It is unclear what exactly you are trying to achieve. If you want *all* usernames then you need a [Scan](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html#QueryAndScan.Scan) and not a Query - since you want all hash keys to be present.